# Multiple Text Styles in TextField in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

Is there a way to take input in multiple text styles in a textfield in Flutter like this?

[image]

Where the user can select a part of the text and edit its style like he wants

Answer (score 2):

You can try use `RichText`

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image: RichText]

Source: [Source on api.flutter.dev](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a TextField with multiple text styles, it is actually pretty easy to set up: You first need to create a custom TextEditingController. You extend TextEditingController and override the `buildTextSpan()` method:

```
class MultiStyleTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan(
      {required BuildContext context,
      TextStyle? style,
      required bool withComposing}) {
    // Let's break our text into blocks divided by spaces
    final words = text.split(' ');
    final textSpanChildren = <TextSpan>[];

    // Add your text styling rules
    for (final word in words) {
      TextStyle wordStyle;
      if (word == 'blue') {
        wordStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.blue);
      } else if (word == 'italic') {
        wordStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
      } else {
        wordStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
      }
      final child = TextSpan(text: word, style: wordStyle);
      textSpanChildren.add(child);
      // Add the space back in
      textSpanChildren.add(TextSpan(text: ' '));
    }
    return TextSpan(children: textSpanChildren);
  }
}
```

Now just add this controller to your TextField:

```
TextField(
  controller: MultiStyleTextEditingController()
    ..text = "This is blue text and this is italic",
);
```

That's it! The word blue and the word italic will have custom styling.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as when I close the keyboard it clears the texts

Comment: Sorry, Prashant, I don't know why that is happening. If you have copied my code exactly it should work. If text is disappearing it could be because your text field background is black and the text is black, so it is invisible. Or you are setting the `text` or `value` property in the `MultiStyleTextEditingController` somewhere else in your code, causing it to change when the keyboard closes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_social_textfield. You can add different styles too.

Comment: this changes style upon certain detections, but I want to make the user change the style by selecting parts of the text and define the style and color manually

Comment: Then you can try html editor https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced